# Trimming Characters From Data in mySQL

Tags: mysql, substring, trim

I'm working in MySQL Pro (5.5.9).

I'm trying to get the year from a column (Game_ID) in my table Games. Unfortunately, the year is surrounded by three characters and then followed by 5 integers. Ex:

SEA200110170

I would ideally be able to keep Game_ID intact, and then create a new column with only the year. So I would remove SEA (or another string of three characters) at the beginning and the string of five integers at the back, and be left with 2001 in a new column titled year_ID.

Any ideas?

I think it's got to do with the trim function, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select Game_ID, substring(Game_ID, 4, 4) as year_ID from your_table
```

It returns the substring from position 4 through 8.

Answer (score 1):

[SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(gameid,4,4) AS year_ID FROM MyTable
```